# A general or simple method to solve this iterative/recursive problem?

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, recursion

I have the following iteration
$$
y_n\mapsto n\sum_{m=1}^{n+1}y_m
$$
starting with $y_1$ being a positive real number. Is there a standard method to find the coeffcients of all $y_n$ after $k<\infty$ iterations? The recursion (?) is applied at every step - here is the first three iterations:
$$
y_1\mapsto y_1+y_2\mapsto(y_1+y_2)+2(y_1+y_2+y_3)\\
\mapsto(y_1+y_2)+2(y_1+y_2+y_3)+2((y_1+y_2)+2(y_1+y_2+y_3)+3(y_1+y_2+y_3+y_4)).
$$
The parentheses are just for a better orientation. After the second iteration the coefficients are $3,3,2$.

It resembles the iteration method for fractals if $y_1$ was complex; except that here only a finite number of steps interests me ($k\to\infty$ obviously diverges).

Any help appreciated - methods, result, literature.

Answer (score 2):

After computing several iterates and looking for a pattern, it seems that the coefficient of $y_n$ after $k$ iterates of this map ($1\le n\le k+1$) is
$$
\frac{(2 k-n+1)!}{2^{k-n+1} (k-n+1)!}.
$$
Given this conjecture, it's probably not too hard to prove it by induction.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - that is splendid. I was ready to attack the problem by the guessing first-proving later method as well. I was wondering whether there is a standardized method (say via a generating function or similar).

Comment: I did look for a generating function approach (always great when they work), but the fact that this is iterates of the same map, rather than a single functional equation, threw me off. That being said, given the final answer, its (two-variable) generating function must be pretty tractable....